# I want to replace a JLabel with another JLabel but keep it in the same position, is this possible?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

Here is the code that I am trying to edit:

```
        game = new JPanel(); 
        ImageIcon bbb = new ImageIcon("bbb.gif");
        JLabel bbbl = new JLabel(bbb);
        ImageIcon bbbH = new ImageIcon("bbbH.gif");
        JLabel bbbHl = new JLabel(bbbH);
        game.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        game.add(bbol);
        game.add(bbgl);
        game.add(bbgrl);
        game.add(bbbl);
        if (flashed == 1)
        {
        game.remove(bbol);
        game.add(bboHl);
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

I want the JLabel `bboHl` to go in the same position as the JLabel `bbol` however there are other JLabels after this one, 3 more to be exact, therefor explaining why the layout is `(GridLayout(2,2))`

Would I need to change the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing/adding components to the layout is way too expensive.
From what I understand, you just want to toogle an image :

Add only one JLabel, and use **setIcon** on it to change the image.

```
    game = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon bbb = new ImageIcon("bbb.gif");
    ImageIcon bbbH = new ImageIcon("bbbH.gif");
    JLabel bbbl = new JLabel(bbb);

    game.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    game.add(bbol);
    game.add(bbgl);
    game.add(bbgrl);
    game.add(bbbl);
    if (flashed == 1) {
        bbbl.setIcon(bbbH);
    } else {
        bbbl.setIcon(bbb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say if there are multiple labels like `label1` ,`label2` , `label3`etc. And you want to set them on the position of label `bbo1`. Then it can be done by getting the location of label `bbo1` and setting it to all other labels.

For Example

```
 label1.setLocation(bbo1.getLocation());
 label2.setLocation(bbo1.getLocation());
 label3.setLocation(bbo1.getLocation());
```